# Addition of big decimal values in javascript for calculating distance on google map

Tags: javascript, php

I am a fresher in coding and working on web designing on googlemap. I have a problem in finding total distance covered by user because i am using a formula for finding distance and then adding this distance one by one.The distance is like 0.41384640620101654 so when i am adding number of values of this type it is giving 0 or error.
here is my code

```php
      getDistance();

             var mn = 0.00;
            function getDistance()
             {


                 for (var i = 0; i < polyline_data.length-1; i++)
             {
                 $lngfrom = polyline_data[i].lng;
                 $lngto = polyline_data[i+1].lng;
                 $latfrom = polyline_data[i].lat;
                 $latto = polyline_data[i+1].lat;
                 $theta = $lngfrom - $lngto;
                    var pi = Math.PI;
                    var x = $latfrom * (pi/180);
                    var y = $latto * (pi/180);
                    var z = $theta * (pi/180);
                 var dist = new Array();        
                 var distance = Math.sin(x) * Math.sin(y)+ Math.cos(x) * Math.cos(y) * Math.cos(z);
                 distance = Math.acos(distance);
                 distance = distance*(180/pi);


                var miles = distance * 60 * 1.8515;
                 distance = miles * 1.609344;
                  distance = parseFloat(distance);
                  //distance = Math.round(distance);
                  //dist = dist.push(distance);
                  //distance+=distance;


        console.log(distance);

    //console.log(all);

            //console.log(distance);
             }



    //var all = new Array();

    //for(j=0;j<polyline_data.length-1;j++)
    //{
        //all[j]=distance;
    //}
        //console.log(all);


             }
```

Comment: https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/ might help

Comment: sir, can you also solve by using my code which i have attached above and i am not using nodejs

Comment: this solution is not working please provide a helpful answer.